# Visual Studio C++ Inputting Data from CSV File into Variable Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, variables, csv

I have been trying to figure this little section of my larger project out for a while now. It has stumped me pretty well too... I am trying to take information from an Excel CSV File (See Example.CSV) and have it input into the Cpp project.. Now before I get to the way I have been working on it, I thought I might first run some other ways by ya guys and see which you thought would be most efficient?

1: Example1.csv: Item Values still following the; `sSwordName, lvlReq, minAtk, maxAtk, atkRate, sPrice, sValue, strReq, atkReq, intReq`. Column Headers as shown in Example.csv.. Would it be ideal to make like a header that pulls Item Information from the CSV file when told to, For example: If the player is at a shop, he wants to appraise his sword. When he clicks on the value button, it searches the 'Sword.csv' file for the item ID(Maybe) and will return the '5th', given the value of the 5th column in that items row is the Value it's worth.. And just create some kind of function that does that for everything? If so, any ideas how to do that.

2: The main way I have been trying to get this to work:
in Example.csv I have all the items values I use in my program.. They are assigned to int and char variables, at least that's my goal.. Please direct to Example.cpp for my (fail) code and explanation..

Example.cpp:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <ios>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>

    using namespace std;

    /*** These are the Variables I use for a weapon, they corrospond according to number in list: Wooden Shortsword is first in the
     *** sSwordName Array, so it's lvl requirment would be 1 since it is first.
     *** Idealy this is the way I want things to work... Unless anyone has a better idea, I am open to hear them. I can always
     *** learn more, especially from others. ***/
    char sSwordName[10][25] =   {"Wooden Shortsword", "Bronze Shortsword", "Iron Shortsword", "Steel Shortsword", "Titanium Shortsword"};
    int sSwordLvlR[10] =    {1, 3, 5, 6, 10};
    int sSwordV[10] =       {5, 10, 18, 25, 50};
    int sSwordP[10] =       {10, 20, 40, 60, 100};
    int sSwordMinAtk[10] =  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int sSwordMaxAtk[10] =  {4, 6, 10, 14, 20};
    int sSwordAtkRate[10] = {0, 2, 3, 4, 6};
    int sSwordStrR[10] =    {1, 6, 11, 16, 22};
    int sSwordAtkR[10] =    {1, 6, 11, 16, 22};
    int sSwordIntR[10] =    {1, 3, 5, 8, 12};

    /*** Now this is as close as I have been able to get to get this to work, sadly it is still off base...
     *** I need it to take for example: Row 1 > Exclude Column 1 > Input Data > Assign to sSwordName[5][25] Array.
     *** My issue is, finding a way to loop it where it takes all the cells in Row 1, ignores the first cell 
     *** (I think making it do like "\n" for it would work? Not sure) and then loop through the rest of the rows
     *** repeating the same algorithm, Ignoring the first cell, inputting, assinging them to the variable arrays?
     *** It is much much easier to edit item stats and add new items in Excel, than having to do it via code as you
     *** may imagine..
     *** I am pretty sure my code is far from what would be best, I bet it needs to be re-written a new way as well..
     *** I would greatly appreciate Anyone who can help me accomplish this task.. It would really make my life
     *** A lot easier, as well as make my project code considerbly shorter.. */

    int main()
{
    int sSwordLvlR;
    double y;
    string data;
    string a;

    ifstream wInv("Example.csv");
    while (getline(wInv, data))
    {
        if (data.empty()) continue;
        istringstream ss( data );
        { 
            string inf;
            getline( ss, inf );
            stringstream( inf ) >> sSwordLvlR;
            cout<<" "<<sSwordLvlR;  
        }
    }
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
/* I have not be able to figure out how to make it take the data for the Names yet either */
```

Example.csv

```
sSwordName,Wooden Shortsword,Bronze Shortsword,Iron Shortsword,Steel Shortsword,Titanium Shortsword
sSwordLvlR,1,3,5,6,10
sSwordMinAtk,0,0,0,0,0
sSwordMaxAtk,4,6,10,14,20
sSwordAtkRate,0,2,3,4,6
sSwordP,10,20,40,60,100
sSwordV,5,10,18,25,50
sSwordStrR,1,6,11,16,22
sSwordAtkR,1,6,11,16,22
sSwordIntR,1,3,5,8,12
```

Example1.csv

```
sSwordName,lvlReq,minAtk,maxAtk,atkRate,sPrice,sValue,strReq,atkReq,intReq
Wooden Shortsword,1,0,4,0,10,5,1,1,1
Bronze Shortsword,3,0,6,2,20,10,6,6,3
Iron Shortsword,5,0,10,3,40,18,11,11,5
Steel Shortsword,6,0,14,4,60,25,16,16,8
Titanium Shortsword,10,0,20,6,100,50,22,22,12
```

As I said in the cpp, I would really really really appreciate anyone who can help me work out that code to it's ideal working state... As well as anyone who wishes to contribute ideas to improve it's overall flow..

Thanks everyone,
Leaum

External Links:

Example.cpp - http://pastebin.com/URWTGVq6
Example.csv - http://pastebin.com/924wvVX2

Comment: Just realized, perhaps it would make it easier if the variables correspond order wise in the CSV as they do in the cpp? Not sure, just a thought.

Comment: Again, I am tired of reading dumped code from DB :( really sad!!!!!

Comment: Can you change the format of the csv, or is that fixed? Parsing something like this would be a lot more natural if you have all the values per sword on a line instead of the other way around as it is now.

Comment: @TeaWolf Actually, I can change it to just about anything I suppose? I mean the main idea is to be able to open it up in Excel, put it all in spread sheets and then make edits or additions.. It can be a .txt or just about anything Excel will do, my question is would it still be compat. with excel? 

On another note, I can even compile the .csv so it would be like;
{1,3,5,6,10} (sSwordLvlR) So it would just be one solid cell. If that makes sense

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get any data out of the file? Does the program run? Does it compile?

Comment: @Valmond It does run, it does compile. When it runs, I have it show the output... It Looks like this (If example.csv)
1
3
5
6
10

It doesn't really show the whole row, and I am NOT sure if it is being assigned to the Variable int sSwordLvlR[10] properly, haven't put it into main code yet due to not being able to import the whole sheet yet

Comment: @Valmond It needs to pull all the data from the .csv(or what ever external doc) I.E: sSwordLvlR,1,3,5,6,10. And assign it to the variable: int sSwordLvlR[100] = {1,3,5,6,10}; Like that essentially.. I guess I failed to leave the int empty in the code (int sSwordLvlR[100] = {};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a function which given a string containing comma separated values will return a vector of those values (as strings). Then when you have that vector you can do the other processing you require (ignoring the first column, converting the strings to integers etc)

Here is that function.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<string> split_at_commas(const string& row)
{
  vector<string> res;
  istringstream buf(row);
  string s;
  while (getline(buf, s, ','))
    res.push_back(s);
  return res;
}

int main()
{
  vector<string> v = split_at_commas("broad sword,abc,123");
  cout << v[0] << '\n' << v[1] << '\n' << v[2] << '\n';
}
```

Output:

broad sword
abc
123

When you have a difficult problem like this it helps to try and break it down into smaller pieces. Looking at your problem it's obvious that you need a function to split strings at commas, so forget about the rest of the problem and write that function first. Then when it's written and working, apply it to the rest of the problem.

**EDIT**

Here for example is how you would use to the above function to assign values to your sSwordLvlR array

```
// read the next line from csv file
vector<string> values = split_at_comma(line);
if (values[0] == "sSwordLvlR") // are we at the sSwordLvlR row?
{
  for (int i = 1; i < values.size(); ++i) // starting at the second column
  {
    sSwordLvlR[i - 1] = convert_string_to_integer(vector[i]);
  }
}
```

`convert_string_to_integer` is another function you should write, and another example of how you should break down a complex probem by writing smaller functions, which you can then put toegther to solve the bigger problem.

**EDIT**

To use this function for the whole CSV file, you have to read your file one line at a time and apply the `split_at_commas` function to each line. Like this

```
string row;
while (getline(wInv, row))
{
  vector<string> values = split_at_commas(row);
  // do something depending on the values you've got
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I follow what you are saying. I do however have a few questions if ya don't mind;  Question 1: The way I have the csv laid out (The ideal one) is Example.csv. Would it be able to take for example 'sSwordLvlR,1,3,5,6,10' Out of that csv, and know that {1,3,5,6,10} needs to be assigned to int sSwordLvlR[10] = {};?  Question 2: I see on the 'vector<string> v = split_at_commas("broad sword,abc,123");' Line you have specifically stated the data, Wouldn't I also have to go through and specify each and every value in the CSV for that to work like that?

Comment: @Leaum: I can see you're having a bit of trouble seeing how to put together functions to make a bigger program. See my edits in the code above.

Comment: Not sure if it just hasn't updated yet, I don't see any changes?

Comment: Haha sorry! Reading over it now.

Comment: `vector.size(); ++i)` & `convert_string_to_integer(vector` Seem to have issues registering in my IDE. The first one is saying the argument list is missing, Second is saying the identifier is undefined :3 know why?

Comment: I also seem to be having issues putting this all together, Not able to compile and test due to the comment above but I just don't see how it would go together... I think I am doing it wrong >.>

Comment: Well `convert_string_to_integer` is undefined because you haven't written it yet. I was thinking you would have a go at writing that yourself. The other error is a typo, I wrote vector when I should have written values, I've fixed it now. (In case it's not clear `values.size()` is the number of values you've read from one row of the CSV file.)

Comment: Ahhh ok, Well I will give it a go... Still though, I am failing to grasp how to put it in with my other stuff.

Comment: Well keep at it, this stuff takes time to learn. And if you get stuck you can always ask another question on this site. But this kind of work, writing functions and putting them together, is the bread and butter of programming.

Comment: Okie, I will accept the answer when I finally get it worked out and make sure it gives the outcome I am trying to achieve.